# Migration to Travel.SE

Tags: feature-request, migration

We seem to get a number of questions here that probably belong on Travel.SE rather than Aviation. Can we add Travel.SE to the list of sites on the "This belongs on another StackExchange network" close reason? Currently, Aviation Meta and Drones and Model Aircraft are the only options  there.

Here's an example that seems like it probably belongs on Travel rather than Aviation (deleted-content privileges required):
[security implication of sharing boarding pass in social networks](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12611/755)

Aviation SE is no longer in beta, avoiding what seems to have been the main reason not to enable migration paths. Since the Drones SE path was added, this wouldn't be the first one enabled.

Comment: for what is worth, I second this.

Comment: I third this. :)

Comment: Mods can move the questions wherever they need to go. I was under the impression that the list of other networks is empty because the site is in beta. But it would be nice to add at least Travel if possible.

Comment: But the fact we can't even *suggest* a site to move it to, is an issue. As you mentioned, possibly one relating to the beta, but still an issue

Comment: @JonStory Agreed. All we can do right now is close it as off-topic and/or flag for mod attention.

Comment: It's 4 years later and we're no longer in beta. Maybe it's time to revisit this? Maybe my memory is playing tricks on me, but it seems that there have been more than 1 question that belonged on [travel.se] in the last week or two, as opposed to the 90-days mentioned in @JonEricson's answer

Comment: @FreeMan I would agree. It might be easier to get more eyes on it, though, if you start a new meta question and link this one. This was actually [brought up again](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3075/755) after we graduated, but that was almost 3 years ago.

Comment: @Someone Given that I asked this in 2015, I think it would be better to create a new question and link back to this one for context rather than editing this one. It will get more views and also preserve the history better (and not already have an upvoted answer that is very out-of-date.)

Answer (score 6):

In the last 90 days, there have been a grand total of one question migrated from Aviation to Travel. There have been 3 questions migrated *to* Aviation (from Travel, IT Security, and Electronic Engineering) which have all been rejected. (If you have 2,000+ reputation, you can see the list in the [moderator tools](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats).)

I know that this is a bit of a Catch-22, but we don't add a default migration path when there aren't a fair number of successful migrations already. This is doubly true for beta sites. For the philosophical underpinnings, please read [Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/). The key takeaway:

> As members of a community, your first loyalty should be to *that* community. When evaluating a question, you shouldn't be looking to push it off on some other site; instead, ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask. **Be a bit jealous of your site**—don't blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don't hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it—and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it.

If you do find a question that's not relevant here and would be ideal for another site, just flag a moderator with the "other" reason and explain why it belongs elsewhere.