# Closing as "belongs on another StackExchange site"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

Sometimes, a question should be closed since it belongs on another SE site, most commonly travel and physics.

Why when I vote to close as such, Aviation Meta is the only choice? Can we get that list of one expanded to include the most common target sites?

Comment: Some of the engineering sites (mechanical, electrical, etc.) would also be good.

Comment: It could be helpful to tag a Q like this as a feature-request for that migration path and perhaps give some examples that have been migrated in the past or that are closed here that could have been migrated.

Comment: Migration paths can be opened now that we're graduating, but generally there needs to be a strong case made for both volume of migrated questions to that destination, and low rejection rate.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1492/64)

Comment: It's worth repeating that the thought *this question belongs on another site* is not a valid close reason! Just because a question might seem more natural on another site doesn't mean it is *necessarily* out of place on Aviation.

Comment: @digitgopher True, but it does often end up being the case with Travel. The physics ones are often reasonably on-topic at either place, but since `"'passenger aspects' of commercial aviation"` are explicitly off-topic for Aviation (as I think they should remain,) the line between Aviation and Travel is less fuzzy.

Comment: @casey I think the one mentioned in [this meta post](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1492/755) is a good example. It was closed as OT here and auto-deleted, but it was actually (IMO, at least) an interesting question for Travel. Also, that meta post is already tagged as feature-request. Should I retag it as discussion so that we don't have duplicate open feature requests?

Comment: @digitgopher But "This question is off-topic here and belongs on another site" *is* a valid close reason.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "This question is off-topic here" is a valid close reason by itself. :)

Comment: @reirab Of course. But "... and you should post it to eggplants.stackexchange.com" is a useful addition.

Answer (score 10):

As we're coming out of Beta we will need to set up the site's initial default migration paths at some point, and I agree that [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com) and [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com) seem like good candidates (and really the *only* major candidates I can think of offhand - [Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) may be a candidate if we get a lot of airline-job-related questions but that seems marginal at best as I doubt those questions would be "migration worthy").

---

I hesitate to advocate for adding migration paths now though for the reasons Jon Ericson noted [in his answer to a previous question on this topic](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1507/64).

The numbers have changed but the logic hasn't: According to our migratio history we've migrated a grand total of 6 questions: 3 to Travel (all open, some reasonably highly voted), 2 to Physics (one at +1, one at -1), 1 to Skeptics (closed as a duplicate).
To me that doesn't scream "pressing need for user-accessible migration paths" at the moment, though it may change as we start getting more traffic.

Comment: Might also consider Space as a candidate destination -- seem to recall a couple of questions better suited for that as well.

Comment: Also, the "low numbers" rationale is a little bit like circular reasoning... it's hard to mark a question as "off topic -- belongs on Travel" so it rarely happens, but then the suggestion to make it easier to recommend this migration is countered with, "rarely happens."  Which might be less the case if it weren't so hard!

Comment: @RalphJ Part of the underlying rationale is that it *should* be hard (and extremely rare) to migrate things. Vote-to-Close Migration is kind of inherently broken IMHO: On low traffic sites like Aviation it works "OK" because the few active close-voters will have trouble reaching a migration consensus on anything but the best and most obvious candidates - only excellent stuff gets migrated. At scale (StackOverflow) migration becomes a giant shovel with which excrement can be flung from your lawn to someone else's. (We don't want to be ["That Site"](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3853/).)

Comment: @RalphJ (To rephrase the circular logic in a less-circular way: "If you don't think the questions are good enough/worth your time to flag a moderator to migrate them why the heck do you want to dump them in someone else's lap to begin with?" -- Lazy migrations "because it's easy" are usually a Bad Thing.)

Comment: We have an option (at least in the tools I can access) that says "belongs on another SE site," with AN option for where (meta). I'd suggest that EITHER this should be fleshed out with a realistic list of destinations to choose from, OR just remove the "meta" option & plainly TELL guys that "if you are voting to close because this is off-topic on av.SE but would be on-topic at another site, *flag it for a moderator* and they can make that happen." Presently, I seem to *almost* be able to mark it this way myself, but nothing tells the REAL way to get it migrated. Ignorant, not lazy!

Comment: I don't see evidence that a recommendation to close is used to dump questions from Aviation.  I believe that we have a more mature community than that.  In all cases I've paid attention to, it's been because the OP would likely get better responses on another site.  If the question is just plain bad, we have good existing ways to close without recommending migration.

Comment: On the other hand, I'd say that the question linked from the other meta post was actually an interesting question, it just happens to be explicitly off-topic for Aviation. It had a comment with 8 votes to move to travel, but instead ended up being closed as off-topic and auto-deleted and so is not counted among the migration history. I suspect that there are quite a few other questions with a similar outcome. However, I don't think it's several per day or anything like that. Maybe a few to several times a month.

Comment: More recently, drones.stackexchange.com (model aircraft) is becoming a common destination.