# Add Travel.SE to the "Belongs On Another StackExchange Site" Option

Tags: feature-request

This is pretty much a duplicate of

[Closing as "belongs on another StackExchange site"](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/closing-as-belongs-on-another-stackexchange-site) and [Migration to Travel.SE](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/migration-to-travel-se) although both the answers to those questions seem to cite that because Aviation.SE is in Beta, it will have to wait.

Well we did it, we graduated and now we can play with the big boys. Can we revisit this topic?

As of right now it seems that the only site we can suggest it be transferred to is Aviation Meta, which is far less common of a migration path than Travel.SE or Physics it would seem.

The second question has an answer that suggests that "it happens infrequently", but I think it happens frequently enough, plus I'm not sure what the harm is in adding it there as a suggestion, it should be much better needing 5 votes to migrate than everybody raising a moderator flag.

So the question is: Can we add Travel.SE and Physics.SE to the "belongs on another StackExchange site" close vote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I select which site to migrate to?](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/why-cant-i-select-which-site-to-migrate-to)

Comment: Can we get a stat on the number of migrations we had recently?

Comment: @kevin I'm not sure that "stat" is useful though. Most of the time we just tell the OP that Travel.SE is more appropriate and the question is closed as off-topic and not migrated. I have a feeling that more often-than-not, people are just closing as off-topic instead of raising a moderator flag to get it migrated.

Comment: Maybe a more useful stat would be the number of closed questions with a comment containing the word "travel" or a link to Travel.SE with more than one up-vote...

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/530230/aviation-travel-se-references

Comment: @RonBeyer The number of questions migrated is generally the more useful stat  (following the "Don't Migrate Crap" axiom: We only want to migrate the best of the best questions). That said though I can see travel.SE as a good migration target based on our migration history (most of what's been sent there has been well-received, and vice-versa)