# Should we add [Travel.SE] as a migration option

Tags: feature-request, migration

We had [this question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/migration-to-travel-se?noredirect=1#comment4583_1492) from way back when we were a beta site. Then [this question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3075/add-travel-se-to-the-belongs-on-another-stackexchange-site-option) was asked shortly after we graduated, and no action was ever taken on either.

I think it's time to take another look at adding a default migration option other than "Aviation Meta" (which seems like a really odd place to migrate questions to).

Most recently there was a question about [future flight fares](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/62474/how-future-flight-fares-are-gathered-by-google-flights) that was closed with comments recommending it be moved to Travel.SE. I'm sure there are others and someone with better Google-fu and/or patience could come up with more.

Comment: Previous questions have basically concluded that the mods are fine with migrating the occasional question themselves, so we'd probably need to see that it's happening more often or there's some benefit to adding the option.

Comment: Anecdotally, I had migrated approx 2-3 questions in a couple of years.

Comment: @Jamiec That might be because the flag for migrating is never used, since you can only select meta. I run across quite a few questions that would work better over at travel.se, but the only real choice is just to close as off-topic and suggest re-posting in comments.

Comment: @Jamiec I think Tom has stated it much better than I have. It's hard to quantify how many questions would be migrated if there was an option to migrate since we don't have that option. Asking out of ignorance of the SE system - Is it difficult to add that option and try it out for 6-12 months, then revert if it's felt that it's being abused, inappropriately used, or otherwise non-beneficial? It seems that there is a lot of resistance to the idea because "we've always done it this way", which, in my mind, is about the worst reason to _not_ change something.